# Datos Repetidos en un Array

Tags: php, json, array

Cuento con el siguiente codigo:

```
$lineas="";
$fechaAnt="";

  for ($l=0; $l < count($dat); $l++) {  

    if($dat[$l][0]!=$fechaAnt || $fechaAnt==""){ //Si tu fecha es diferente a la anterior o es igual a vacio porque es la primera vez

        $lineas=$dat[$l][1]; //inicia lineas

    }else if($dat[$l][0]==$fechaAnt){ //si tu fecha es igual a la anterior

        $lineas=$lineas.",".$dat[$l][1]; //sigue concatenando

    }
    $fechaAnt=$dat[$l][0]; //Asignas valor a la fecha anterior que es la que acabas de pasar

    $hola[]= [$dat[$l][0],$lineas];
  }
```

donde el arreglo $dat =

```
0:["2016-11-09", 1]
1:["2016-11-09", 1]
2:["2016-11-15", 1]
3:["2016-11-16", 1]
4:["2016-11-16", 1]
5:["2016-11-17", 2]
```

Lo que hace es que si es la misma fecha en este caso `$dat[$l][0]` me concatene los valores, y lo hace el problema es que me pone la fecha con el primer dato.

```
0:["2016-11-09", 1]      //<- Esto no debería estar 
1:["2016-11-09", "1,1"]  //<- Esto si debería estar 
2:["2016-11-15", 1]      //<- Esto si debería estar ya que solo hay un dato en ea fecha       
3:["2016-11-16", 1]    //<- Esto no debería estar 
4:["2016-11-16", "1,1"]   //<- Esto si debería estar 
5:["2016-11-17", 2] //<- Esto si debería estar ya que solo hay un dato en ea fecha
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar ¿?

Comment: `0:["2016-11-09", 1]      //<- Esto no debería estar` lo que necesitas es que lo que se guarda en la posición `0` y la posición `3` no deberían estar en el arreglo final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema que planteas agregue la variable `$repetidos` que se encargará de contar las fechas que se repiten y la variable `$hola` la he movido del sitio donde se le asignaban los valores. Lo que se realiza es que cuando se consigue una fecha que coincide con la anterior en la posición de `'lineas'` se asigna la concatenación de `$lineas`.

```
$lineas="";
$fechaAnt="";
$repetidos=1; //agregado

for ($l=0; $l < count($dat); $l++) {  

if($dat[$l][0]!=$fechaAnt || $fechaAnt==""){ //Si tu fecha es diferente a la anterior o es igual a vacio porque es la primera vez

    $lineas=$dat[$l][1]; //inicia lineas
    $hola[]= [$dat[$l][0],$lineas]; //Se asigna la la fecha y las lineas

}else if($dat[$l][0]==$fechaAnt){ //si tu fecha es igual a la anterior

    $lineas=$lineas.",".$dat[$l][1]; //sigue concatenando
    $hola[$l-$repetidos][1]= $lineas; //Se asigna solo la variable $lineas
    $repetidos++;

}
$fechaAnt=$dat[$l][0]; //Asignas valor a la fecha anterior que es la que acabas de pasar

}
```

[Enlace a prueba del código](http://rextester.com/XDRDRG27761)

Answer (score 1):

un codigo mas facil creo que lo complicastess.

```
<?php
$data[] =  (["2016-11-09", 1]);
$data[] =  (["2016-11-09", 1]);
$data[] =  (["2016-11-15", 1]);
$data[] =  (["2016-11-16", 1]);
$data[] =  (["2016-11-16", 1]);
$data[] =  (["2016-11-17", 2]);


$final= array();
$total = count($data);
  for ($l=0; $l < $total ; $l++) {  
      if(!isset($final[$data[$l][0]])){
        $final[$data[$l][0]] = $data[$l][1];
      }else{
        $final[$data[$l][0]] .= ','.$data[$l][1];
      }

  }

foreach ($final as $key => $valor) {
    echo "para la fecha " . $key . " el valor es ". $valor ."<br/>"; 
}
```

el resultado arrojado es:

```
para la fecha 2016-11-09 el valor es 1,1
para la fecha 2016-11-15 el valor es 1
para la fecha 2016-11-16 el valor es 1,1
para la fecha 2016-11-17 el valor es 2
```

codigo demo  [aqui](http://rextester.com/EPPOQ75437)

Comment: y al valor que concateno de podría quitar las "" ya que cuando lo mando en json lo pone "1,1" y lo necesito  1,1 si las comillas

Comment: En realidad quiciera que cuando mando imprimir el json y tomo los datos me lo imprima de la siguiente manera :

`0:["2016-11-09", 1, 2]
1:["2016-11-15", 1]
2:["2016-11-16", 1, 4]
3:["2016-11-17", 2]` 
que no me muestre las "" el los que estan concatenados